# How can I have two objects access the same array

Tags: javascript, es6-class

Class A is instantiated to an object that has an array named `this.people` that is filled with a bunch of data. Class A instantiates an object of class B and `this.people` is passed to it's constructor. If object B updates the array, when object A updates it, it overwrites the changes from object B. How can I fix this?

Comment: So you want class B to have a reference to a copy of the array rather than to the original?

Comment: When you update the array, don't assume it's how you last left it, since you're sharing the reference.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you're passing a reference of A's `people` array to B's constructor. You want to make either a "shallow copy" or a "deep copy" of A's `people` array, since you want B's `people` array contents to be different.

With a "shallow copy" you copy all of the primitive values in the array to the new one, but if you have compound values (arrays or objects) inside the array, then only the reference to them will be copied, so any changes that you do to the compound values will be reflected in both A and B. With a "deep copy", both primitive and compound values (and not just their references) will be copied to a new place in memory.

If you don't have objects and arrays inside the `people` array, you can do a shallow copy using `Array.from(a.people)`. Otherwise, you can do a deep copy with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a.people))`

Snippet:

```js
class B {
  constructor(_people) {
    // shallow copy:
    this.people = Array.from(_people);

    // deep copy:
    //this.people = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(_people));
  }
}
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.people = [];
  }
  func() {
    this.objB = new B(this.people);
    //do something
  }
}

// Usage Example
let objA = new A();
objA.people.push("A");
objA.func();
objA.objB.people.push("B");
console.log(objA.people.toString());
console.log(objA.objB.people.toString());
```

Some helpful links:
https://medium.com/@gamshan001/javascript-deep-copy-for-array-and-object-97e3d4bc401a

https://dev.to/samanthaming/how-to-deep-clone-an-array-in-javascript-3cig

Comment: From OPs description, it sounded more like they were not doing any copy at all, and a shallow one would have sufficed.

Comment: @Bergi What I understood is that he does not want A's changes to overwrite B's changes, so they need to be different arrays in memory. Will's answer does a deep copy in an interesting way that should be faster than using JSON though, kudos to him. ^^

Comment: @Will doesn't do a deep (or shallow) copy at all, he just nests the array in a new array. The `wilsons.people` are an array of arrays (or later, an array of an array and a string). This is not desirable.

Comment: @Bergi You're right, I didn't notice that. I suppose `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` are the way to go.

Comment: A simple `people.slice()`, `Array.from(people)` or `[...people]` would most likely have sufficed

Comment: @Bergi Ah, I see. It will depend on whether he has an object inside the array or not. Because if he does, then changes to the object will be reflected in both arrays, since only references are copied.

Comment: Indeed. But without the OP having shown any code, it's pointless to discuss :-)

Answer (score -1):

Give each class its own version of `people`

```js
class A{
    constructor(){
        this.people = ["bob","jane","john"]
        this.objB = new B(this.people)   
    }
}

class B{
    constructor(people){
        this.people = people
    }
}

let objA = new A()
objA.objB.people.push("a")
objA.people.push("b")
console.log(objA.people, objA.objB.people)
```

Comment: Now where in your code is the "own version"? The snippet demonstrates exactly the undesired behaviour.

Comment: @Bergi he says "If object B updates the array, when object A updates it, it overwrites the changes from object B." My "own version" fixes this.

Comment: Your code does not construct an "own version" anywhere. It uses the same array in both objects, and the log shows that `a` and `b` appear in the (same) array on both objects.

Comment: @Bergi Okay, thanks for your input

Answer (score -1):

Pass the array by value with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
class Family {
  constructor(people) {
    this.people = people;
  }
}

let members = ["mom", "dad"];

let smiths = new Family(members);
let joneses = new Family(smiths.people); // pass by reference

joneses.people.push("Billy");
console.log(smiths.people); // changes to ["mom","dad","Billy"]

let wilsons = new Family([...smiths.people]); // pass by value

wilsons.people.push("Suzy");
console.log(smiths.people); // remains ["mom","dad","Billy"]
```

Comment: There's no destructuring assignment in your code?

Comment: `let wilsons = new Family([smiths.people]);` The brackets destructure the array into a new array.

Comment: No, they don't. Destructuring includes a lefthand-side value, e.g. an assignment target or a parameter definition. You just construct an array containing another array.

Comment: Fine, what do you call it, then?

Comment: It's an array literal. But it doesn't even give the correct result (try logging `wilsons.people` instead of logging `smiths.people` again), maybe you meant something else?

Comment: I meant smiths.people to show that updating wilsons doesn't affect smiths.

Comment: Yes, but `wilsons.people` has the wrong value. You could also have done `let wilsons = new Family([]);` and the smiths wouldn't have been affected.

Comment: Ah, missing three dots. Fixed.

Comment: Oh, that's not destructuring, that's spread syntax in an array literal